# HTML5 How can I use mouse event(over, click) to drawn component

Tags: javascript, html, events, canvas, mouse

I want to below funtion.

1. add to mouse event(over, click) drawn component

   - lineto
   - mouse over or click drawn line, display message
2. one more want.. possible to event run IE11, Chrome, Safari...

   [original code.]

   ```
           <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
           <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
           <!doctype html>
           <html>

           <head>
               <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../css/style.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
               <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
               <script src="../js/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

           <style>
               body{ background-color: white; }
               canvas{border:1px solid red;}
                   html, body {
                      width: 100%;
                      height: 100%;
                      margin:0px 0px 0px 10px;
                   }
               footer{display:block; border-top:1px solid orange;margin:10px;font-family:"Trebuchet MS",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-weight:bold;}
               article{display:block; font-family:Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times, serif; margin:5px;}
           </style>

           <script>
           $(document).ready(function()
           {
            $('body').hide().fadeIn(1000); 
           });
           </script>

           <%
                   int chrcount = 10; //servlet return
           %>
               <img id="canvasImg">

               <canvas id="canvas" width="<%=chrcount*200%>" height="2000" style="display:none;"></canvas>

           <script type="text/javascript">

                   var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
                   var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

                   var start_position = 100;
                   var end_position = 200;
                   var RGBcolor = [];

                   var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
                   var canvasHeight = canvas.height; 

           <%
               DBManagerPepper dbmanagerpepper = new DBManagerPepper();

               String chrLength_sql = null;
               String bpLength_sql = null;
               String alignment_sql = null;
               String cMLength_sql = null;
               String AllChr_sql = null;

               String organismCode = request.getParameter("organismCode") ; //servlet return

               int canvasWidth = chrcount * 500;
                   //cM length
                   AllChr_sql = "select distinct ch_no from geneticmap_info_t";

                   try{
                       dbmanagerpepper.rs=dbmanagerpepper.stmt.executeQuery(AllChr_sql);
                   }catch(Exception e){
                       System.out.println(e);
                   }

                   while (dbmanagerpepper.rs!=null && dbmanagerpepper.rs.next()) {     

                       int R = (int)(Math.random()*256);
                       int G = (int)(Math.random()*256);
                       int B= (int)(Math.random()*256);
                       String RGB = R+","+G+","+B;
                       //System.out.println(RGB);
                       //RGBcolor.put(dbmanagerpepper.rs.getString("ch_no"), RGB);

                       %>
                           RGBcolor.push({ch_no:'<%=dbmanagerpepper.rs.getString("ch_no")%>',rgb:'<%=RGB%>'}); 
                       <%

                   } 

           %>

                   //alert(RGBcolor[1].rgb);

           <%
               for(int i=1;i<chrcount;i++){
                   %>
                       var i = <%=i%>  
                   <%
                   //cM length
                   cMLength_sql = "select max(position) as max_cM_position from geneticmap_info_t where  organismcode='"+organismCode+"' and ch_no='"+i+"'";

                   try{
                       dbmanagerpepper.rs=dbmanagerpepper.stmt.executeQuery(cMLength_sql);
                   }catch(Exception e){
                       System.out.println(e);
                   }

                   %>

                   var cM_length = <% while (dbmanagerpepper.rs!=null && dbmanagerpepper.rs.next()) { %><%=dbmanagerpepper.rs.getInt("max_cM_position")%><% } %>;  


                   <%

                   //bp length
                   bpLength_sql = "select max(cov_position) as max_cov_position  from physicalmap_info_t where organismcode='"+organismCode+"' and lg_no='"+i+"'";

                   try{
                       dbmanagerpepper.rs=dbmanagerpepper.stmt.executeQuery(bpLength_sql);
                   }catch(Exception e){
                       System.out.println(e);
                   }

                   %>
                       var bp_length = <% while (dbmanagerpepper.rs!=null && dbmanagerpepper.rs.next()) { %><%=dbmanagerpepper.rs.getInt("max_cov_position")%><% } %>; 


                   <%
                   //align(cM-bp)
                   //alignment_sql = "select a.markername as physicalmap_markername, a.lg_no as physicalmap_lg_no, a.cov_position as physicalmap_cov_position, b.ch_no as geneticmap_ch_no, b.position as geneticmap_position from physicalmap_info_t a, geneticmap_info_t b where a.lg_no='"+i+"' and a.organismcode='"+organismCode+"' and a.organismcode=b.organismcode and a.lg_no=b.ch_no and a.markername=b.markername order by a.markerseq;";

                   alignment_sql = "select a.markername as physicalmap_markername, a.lg_no as physicalmap_lg_no, a.cov_position as physicalmap_cov_position, b.ch_no as geneticmap_ch_no, b.position as geneticmap_position from physicalmap_info_t a, geneticmap_info_t b where a.lg_no='"+i+"' and a.organismcode='"+organismCode+"' and a.organismcode=b.organismcode and a.markername=b.markername order by a.markerseq;";

                   try{
                       dbmanagerpepper.rs=dbmanagerpepper.stmt.executeQuery(alignment_sql);
                   }catch(Exception e){
                       System.out.println(e);
                   }
                   %>

                   var physicalmap_markername = [
                   <% while (dbmanagerpepper.rs!=null && dbmanagerpepper.rs.next()) { %>
                      '<%=dbmanagerpepper.rs.getString("physicalmap_markername")%>', 
                   <% } %>
                   ];
                   <%
                       dbmanagerpepper.rs.beforeFirst();   
                   %>


                   var physicalmap_lg_no = [ 
                   <% while (dbmanagerpepper.rs!=null && dbmanagerpepper.rs.next()) { %>
                      <%=dbmanagerpepper.rs.getInt("physicalmap_lg_no")%>, 
                   <% } %>
                   ];
                   <%
                       dbmanagerpepper.rs.beforeFirst();   
                   %>

                   var physicalmap_cov_position = [ 
                   <% while (dbmanagerpepper.rs!=null && dbmanagerpepper.rs.next()) { %>
                      <%=dbmanagerpepper.rs.getInt("physicalmap_cov_position")%>, 
                   <% } %>
                   ];
                   <%
                       dbmanagerpepper.rs.beforeFirst();   
                   %>


                   var geneticmap_ch_no = [ 
                   <% while (dbmanagerpepper.rs!=null && dbmanagerpepper.rs.next()) { %>
                      <%=dbmanagerpepper.rs.getInt("geneticmap_ch_no")%>, 
                   <% } %>
                   ];
                   <%
                       dbmanagerpepper.rs.beforeFirst();   
                   %>


                   var geneticmap_position = [ 
                   <% while (dbmanagerpepper.rs!=null && dbmanagerpepper.rs.next()) { %>
                      <%=dbmanagerpepper.rs.getInt("geneticmap_position")%>, 
                   <% } %>
                   ];
                   <%
                       dbmanagerpepper.rs.beforeFirst();   
                   %>


                     orfSize = canvasWidth*(<%=chrcount*5%>);

                     ctx.lineWidth=12;
                     var offset = 2500000;
                     var start=offset;
                     var end=bp_length+offset;

                     ctx.beginPath();

                     ctx.fillStyle = "rgb("+RGBcolor[i-1].rgb+")";
                     ctx.font = "bold 12pt Courier";
                     ctx.textBaseline = 'Top';
                     ctx.fillText("Chr"+i,start_position-30,20);

                     ctx.strokeStyle ="rgb("+RGBcolor[i-1].rgb+")";
                     ctx.moveTo(start_position,start/orfSize);
                     ctx.lineTo(start_position,end/orfSize); 

                     ctx.stroke();

                     var end=cM_length+offset;

                     ctx.beginPath();
                     ctx.strokeStyle ='rgb(1,176,241)';

                     ctx.moveTo(end_position,start/orfSize);
                     ctx.lineTo(end_position,end/orfSize); 

                     ctx.stroke();

                     ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(144,167,198)';
                     ctx.font = "bold 12pt Courier";
                     ctx.textBaseline = 'Top';
                     ctx.fillText("cM",end_position,end/orfSize+10);

                     var count=1;

                     for( k=0;k<physicalmap_lg_no.length;k++){

                         var start=physicalmap_cov_position[k]+offset;
                         var end=geneticmap_position[k]+offset;

                         ctx.beginPath();

                           if(physicalmap_lg_no[k] == geneticmap_ch_no[k]){
                             ctx.lineWidth = 0.7;  
                             ctx.strokeStyle ="rgb(144,167,198)";
                             ctx.moveTo(start_position+5,start/orfSize);
                             ctx.lineTo(start_position+95,end/orfSize); 
                             ctx.stroke();
                           }

                           else{

                               if(geneticmap_ch_no[k] != i){
                                 ctx.strokeStyle ="rgb("+RGBcolor[geneticmap_ch_no[k]-1].rgb+")";
                                 ctx.lineWidth=13;
                                 ctx.moveTo(start_position-15,start/orfSize);
                                 ctx.lineTo(start_position-15,(start+100000)/orfSize); 
                                 ctx.stroke();

                               }

                          }

                         count = count+1;
                     }


                     for( k=0;k<physicalmap_lg_no.length;k++){

                         var start=physicalmap_cov_position[k]+offset;
                         var end=geneticmap_position[k]+offset;

                         var start_position_align = 100;
                         var end_position_align = 200;

                         ctx.beginPath();

                           if(physicalmap_lg_no[k] == geneticmap_ch_no[k]){
                             ctx.lineWidth = 0.7;  
                             ctx.strokeStyle ="rgb(144,167,198)";
                             ctx.moveTo(start_position+5,start/orfSize);
                             ctx.lineTo(start_position+95,end/orfSize); 
                             ctx.stroke();
                           }

                           else{

                               if(geneticmap_ch_no[k] != i){

                                 start_position_align = start_position_align+((geneticmap_ch_no[k]-1)*200);
                                 end_position_align = end_position_align+((geneticmap_ch_no[k]-1)*200);

                                 //alert(((geneticmap_ch_no[k]-1)*200));

                                 ctx.strokeStyle ="rgb("+RGBcolor[physicalmap_lg_no[k]-1].rgb+")";
                                 ctx.lineWidth=13;
                                 ctx.moveTo(end_position_align+15,end/orfSize);
                                 ctx.lineTo(end_position_align+15,(end+100000)/orfSize); 
                                 ctx.stroke();
                               }

                          }

                         count = count+1;
                     }

                   start_position = start_position+200;
                   end_position = end_position+200;

                   <%



               }


           %>
                 // save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
                 var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

                 // set canvasImg image src to dataURL
                 // so it can be saved as an image
                 document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = dataURL;
           </script>

           </html>
   ```

Comment: Your question is unclear. :-(

Comment: sorry. I rewrite orginal full source.